# Can the final outcome of a mission, or the effects it has on later missions, be changed in one playthrough?

Tags: dishonored

I started a Ghost/Shadow/Mostly Flesh and Steel/Clean Hands playthrough.
In "High Overseer Campbell", I completely avoided Granny Rags because I didn't know her tasks could be completed without locking these achievements...

Later I found out that it is possible, and that I need to complete at least one of Granny Rags' and Slackjaw's tasks to unlock their area in "The Flooded District" - and I need that for the "Art Dealer" achievement.

I replayed "High Overseer Campbell", hoping that GR&SJ's area in "The Flooded District" would be unlocked if I did Granny's tasks and completed the mission - but it wasn't! (I did both of Sj's tasks in "House of Pleasure" on the 1st try btw.)

Is there a way to change my previous choices in my playthrough that's already at "The Flooded District"?

Comment: You already tried changing past missions and saw it didn't work. What are you asking now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to change previous choices in an existing playthrough. Your only option now is to replay through the game starting from the High Overseer Campbell mission, and reach the Flooded District mission again.